# getBoundingClientRect(); Does not working ..?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knapsack-problem

I want to know .mydiv how far from the top of the body and for this purpose I used the code getBoundingClientRect()  but it doesn't work, this is my code :

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <h1>Elemet.GetBoundingClientRect();</h1>
    <div class="myDiv">blah balh balh</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          var div = document.querySelector(".myDiv");
         var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(rect);
    </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

#### This is the result :

```
`DOMRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, …} 

bottom: 0
height: 0
left: 0
right: 0
top: 0
width: 0
x: 0
y: 0
__proto__: DOMRect`
```

The result only gives me zero numbers 
*how Can I solve this problem please help* ???!

Comment: in which browser and version does this happen?

Comment: in chrome browser Version 85.0.4183.102

Comment: You're right, I tried it in the { microsoft Edge and internet explorer } Browser and It's work perfectly . Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

It is working. Try to remove the css and test again.

```html
<h1>Elemet.GetBoundingClientRect();</h1>
    <div class="myDiv">blah balh balh</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          var div = document.querySelector(".myDiv");
         var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(rect);
    </script>
```

Comment: i'll try it but it doesn't working but the problem in a chrome Browser and i test it again in the internet Explorer browser and It's work perfectly. / 
Thank U So much to help me